# Client doesn't emit event in socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io, jestjs

I have followed the socket.io testing guide [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/testing/#Example-with-jest) it showed the server emitting some event and the client will receive it, but I want it the other way around. The client should send some data and the server will receive it this is my code

```js
  test("it should send valid file", (done) => {
    const id = "userId";
    const fileName = __dirname + "/videoTst.webm";
    
    serverSocket.on("receive_video_file", (data) => {
        console.log("called");
        expect(data.file).toEqual(prepareFile(fileName));
        expect(data.id).toEqual(id);
        done();
    });

    sendVideo(clientSocket, prepareFile(fileName), id, done);
    });
```

and the `sendVideo` function

```js
const sendVideo = (socket: any, file: any, usrId: string, callback: any) => {
  socket.emit("receive_video_file", { file, id: usrId });
};
```

This result timeout error because the event wasn't received or maybe wasn't emitted at all. I've added a console log in the callback function and it wasn't called.

**Note:** when I tried the emmit from the server

```js
    serverSocket.emit("hello", {word: "world", file: prepareFile(fileName)});
    clientSocket.on("hello", (args: any) => {
      console.log(args);
      expect(args.word).toEqual("world");
      done();
    });
```

It worked!
I'm definitely missing something here. I'm very new to socket.io so I couldn't figure it out.

**Update:** when I set `DEBUG=socket.io:client*,socket.io:server*` I've found that the only `type 0` messages are being sent

```
$ jest
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/socket.io"} +1ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +1ms
  socket.io:server incoming connection with id uI2s4pGCSIJ5LiuFAAAA +34ms
  socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:client writing packet {"type":0,"data":{"sid":"OSg_9WK_p05JeRZCAAAB"},"nsp":"/"} +3ms
  socket.io:client client close with reason transport error +137ms
  socket.io:server incoming connection with id csCLNa-khLRO0xLNAAAC +1s
  socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +1s
  socket.io:client writing packet {"type":0,"data":{"sid":"aeyzUguWgcuJFZwFAAAD"},"nsp":"/"} +2ms
  socket.io:client client close with reason forced close +4s
 FAIL  test/unit/SendVideo/SendVideo.test.ts (10.496 s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the [`maxHttpBufferSize`](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#maxHttpBufferSize) and my file was 2MB. when I increased the buffer size it worked